# I cannot do load test using jmeter in XMPP server, I had added all plugins and given xmpp connection, samplers for connecting login, and all

Tags: jmeter, xmpp, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I cannot load test the chat application in XMPP server using jmeter, I found all XMPP samplers from connect, login till disconnect as error. Please help!

[I get this error in the connect server sampler itself and thereby all samplers are error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Poss2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will be able to help without seeing the error details so going forward make sure to include essential information about your test, i.e.

- Screenshots of your [XMPP Samplers](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/XMPPSampler.md)
- Output of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in screenshot or textual form
- Relevant entries from [`jmeter.log` file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)

In the meantime check out [XMPP Load Testing - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide) - it contains comprehensive information on how to configure XMPP Test Elements and simulate different types of events (connect/disconnect, log in, get contacts list, setting status, etc.) as well as [example test plans](https://github.com/raladev/load/tree/master/xmpp)

Comment: org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.IQReplyFilter accept
WARNING: Rejected potentially spoofed reply to IQ-packet. Filter settings: packetId=LH9xR-64, to=null, local=null, server=serveraddress. Received packet with from=userid@serverdomain. In view result listener I am getting
Load time:1041
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:932
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:932
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
SampleResult fields:
ContentType:

Comment: Have been trying to connect and login using xmpp sampler. Login doesn't succeed though I am able to login to xmpp server using same credentials

Comment: stream:error (invalid-from) text: Improper 'from' attribute